# Providing exam solutions?

Tags: united-kingdom, internet

Some universities do not provide solutions/mark-schemes to exam papers. If someone (e.g. a student) was to upload online (e.g. via a blog or in a document) solutions that they themselves have made would this be legal?

**Additionally**

On a very related topic what about uploading the answers to problems in textbooks that do not come with answers only problems?

Comment: I voted to close because this question is about *specific* legal advice. If the author were to rephrase the question in a general manner, I see no problem with it.

Comment: @Viktor This question is hardly specific.  It doesn't take too much imagination to replace "I" with "someone."  It is not a question asking "what should I do" but rather about what the law says.  Note the use of the conditional.  Would it be too specific to ask a question like "I own a gun; would it be legal for me to carry it in my checked bag on a flight from JFK?"?

Comment: @phoog what's the point of having the rule of we're not going to follow it?

Comment: @Viktor my point is that you are misinterpreting the rule.

Comment: @Viktor I have tried to edit it to make it a bit more general, feel free to change it if you think it can be made more so.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a lawyer and I have never been to the UK so you'd be a fool to rely on my advice.

You should be able to state that you took an exam, were asked such and such questions, and provided such and such answers. You should be able to also say which ones were marked right and which were marked wrong. I'm aware that "fair use" doesn't exist as such in the UK, but I believe there's a similar concept there that should cover this reasonable situation.

Now it's entirely possible that a condition of attending the University was agreeing not to do what you're proposing. If that's the case and the agreement is legally valid, then you might be in breach of the agreement and the University could have remedies under the agreement and/or the law. For instance, your University might have an academic honesty policy that prevents you from doing this and there may be penalties for violating it, likely up to and including expulsion. I somewhat doubt that they'd try to come after you for more than that but I'd read the policies.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, this is very helpful. Just to let you know I have added a slight addition to my question.